# Send Email from Java with default mail client

Tags: java

I have Java code, that should send emails.
The default mail client opens correctly and also the receiver as well as the subject is smoothly set, but the body is not set. No body is shown. Here's my code:

```
public void emailOhneStandort() throws URISyntaxException {

    try {

        composeEmail("benjamin.koubik@daimler.com", "Thanks for the snippet!",
                "Hello Raffael,\r\nthis mail was initiated by Java.");
    } catch (Exception err) {
        err.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Done!");
}

public static void composeEmail(String receiver, String subject, String body) throws Exception {

    String mailto = "mailTo:" + receiver;
    mailto += "?subject=" + uriEncode(subject);
    mailto += "&body=" + uriEncode(body);

    String cmd = "";
    String os = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
    if (os.contains("win")) {
        cmd = "cmd.exe /c start " + mailto;
    } else if (os.contains("osx")) {
        cmd = "open " + mailto;
    } else if (os.contains("nix") || os.contains("aix") || os.contains("nux")) {
        cmd = "xdg-open " + mailto;
    }
    // Call default mail client with paramters
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

}

private static String uriEncode(String in) {
    String out = new String();
    for (char ch : in.toCharArray()) {
        out += Character.isLetterOrDigit(ch) ? ch : String.format("%%%02X", (int) ch);
    }
    return out;
}
```

Comment: You'd have got a clue to the error if you had not ignored the error message from the `exec` call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From trying on Windows, I find that I need to escape the `&` with a `^`.

So, if I do this:

```
C:\>start mailto:test@example.com?subject=foo&body=bar
```

I get the following error:

```
'body' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

and my email client opens with the subject populated but not the body.

If I do this:

```
C:\>start mailto:test@example.com?subject=foo^&body=bar
```

then it works as expected.

I daresay the equivalent will happen in other environments, but can't test that at the moment.

For the record, it seems worth adding that this is a bit of an odd requirement, and if it's something you're doing for production code that will be used by anyone other than yourself, it's probably not the best approach!

Comment: Correct. Might also add that it would be `\&`, `\?` and `\%` in a unix environment. (or just put the whole string in single quotes, but I'm not sure it's cross-terminal)

Comment: I know the OP is using a different approach but when using the [`Desktop.mail(URI)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#mail(java.net.URI)) method I don't have to escape anything (at least on Windows).